# Where to place the constructor?

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I fixed up the code and updated, but now I do not know where to place the constructor:

```
private JPanel panel;
public RollButton(JPanel panel){
    this.panel = panel;
}
```

I looked at some examples of where to place the constructor and it seems like it is placed around my `RollButton` class, but I have tried to put it in multiple times and in multiple places but I cannot seem to get it right.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRollGUI {

    public static JLabel label;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JButton buttonRollDie;
    private static JLabel diceRoll;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Roll GUI");
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,5,10));
        button = new JButton("Roll");;

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(750, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.setActionCommand("Roll");
        button.addActionListener(new RollButton());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.add(button);


        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }

    private static class RollButton implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            int roll = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
            ImageIcon dice = null;

            if(roll == 1){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/dice_face_1.png");
            }
            else if(roll == 2){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_2.png");
            }
            else if(roll == 3){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_3.png");
            }
            else if(roll == 4){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_4.png");
            }
            else if(roll == 5){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_5.png");
            }
            else if(roll == 6){
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_6.png");;
            }
            JLabel diceRoll = new JLabel("",dice, JLabel.CENTER);

            panel.add(diceRoll);
            panel.revalidate();    



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your **full** error message please. You're missing the top most important part.

Comment: Alright, added the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple `NullPointerException`, which should have being fixed by checking the nearest line to the cause of the exception within your source code and/or debugging the program

When I ran the program, I got the following exception...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dicerollgui.DiceRollGUI$RollButton.actionPerformed(DiceRollGUI.java:55)
```

Which pointed me to `label.setText(" ");` within the `actionPerformed` method...

```
        if(rolldie.equals("Roll")) {
            label.setText(" ");
```

This automatically suggested to me that `label` has not yet being initialised (and therefore is `null`).

**Updated...**

This...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(dice6);
```

Seems very weird to me.  Basically on each dice roll, you are creating a new `JLabel` and a new `JFrame` but you're not  showing the resulting frame...

Instead, you should have a single `JLabel` which maintains the value of the last roll and simply use either `setText` or `setIcon` to change it's state based on your requirements.

**Updated with example**

[image: Feeling lucky?]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DiceRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DiceRoll();
    }

    public DiceRoll() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new DicePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DicePane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel diceRoll;
        private JButton rollDice;

        public DicePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            diceRoll = new JLabel();
            Font font = diceRoll.getFont();
            diceRoll.setFont(font.deriveFont(128f));
            diceRoll.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(diceRoll);

            rollDice = new JButton("Papper needs a new pair of shoes");
            rollDice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int roll = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
                    diceRoll.setText(Integer.toString(roll));
                }
            });

            add(rollDice, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }        
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I went to all the lines and changed it, I have no errors now but when I run my GUI and press the button nothing happens :\

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? I've tried to fix this myself but I cannot seem to fix it.

Comment: Create an instance variable of a `JLabel`, instantiate in your constructor, add it to your frame and then simply use `setText` or `setIcon` to change its values when `actionPerformed` is called...You got your button onto the screen, so the concept it very simular

Comment: Can you show an example? I am new to java swing and not that good at coding, also the random generator works too right?

Comment: Thank you for the example but I still do not understand what to do with the frame.add(this) and all that, I've changed it multiple times but still cannot fix it :\

Comment: You can't add a window to window.  Get rid of it.  Your example extends from `JFrame` so you can simply use that directly...

Comment: Use JFrame directly? I tried to put add(diceOne) but it gives me an error saying it can't find the symbol.

Comment: No sorry, must be thinking about a different question.  No, simply get rid of the `frame.add`, there's no need for it.  Using a single instance of `JLabel` is more then enough

Comment: how would I use JLabel replacing the frame.add? I think I just need these lines to work. I replaced the frame.add with label.setIcon(diceOne); it compiles but when I run it, it gives me the same errors.

Comment: Make sure you create an instance of the JLabel on the constructor before you add it to the frame

Comment: I'm passed that right now and do not know where to put the constructor , I updated the post :\

Comment: You see how you're adding the button?  You need to do the same thing with your label, it's also demonstrated in my example

Answer (score 7):

Edit: It's a NullPointerException or as some of us say, an NPE.

Key here is to learn how to fix most NPE's when you get them:

1. Find the line that throws the NPE. The exceptions stacktrace will tell you, for example yours is telling you `at   DiceRollGUI$RollButton.actionPerformed(DiceRollGUI.java:40)` meaning at line 40 in your DiceRollGUI.java class.
2. Check to see if you're calling any methods on variables on that line or if you are "dereferencing" a variable in some other way.
3. Check to see if any of the variables on that line are null (a debugger can help, or failing that, a couple of println's ***before*** the line of interest can help).
4. Then trace back in your program to see why that variable is null when you thought that it wasn't.

In your case your JLabel, label, is null because, well because you never initialize it. You need to assign it a new JLabel object before trying to use it.

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, in the future, if you ask questions about exceptions or errors, always post the full exception or error message, and indicate for us which line is causing the problem. The error message will usually tell you exactly which line it is, but you will have to translate the line numbers to the actual line in your program.

Comment: Alright, so I went to all the lines and changed it, I have no errors now but when I run my GUI and press the button nothing happens :\